# McCLIM text labels access

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, mcclim

Is there a way to change text in the simple label `(screen :label :text "input")`? Tried different things, but none worked. Setting gadget value, accessing text slot..

Also for some reason creating label without `:text` and running the app reboots my user session.